# Plotting Learning Curves [Scitkit Learn] - How to set x-axis values/labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Im trying to plot a learning curve using this.

http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/plot_learning_curve.html.

I have a fixed set of training sizes i want to look at.

So in the plot_learning_curve function i manually set. Training size to [10, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000]. However, the x-axis don't up date to show those specific values on the x-axis.

```
def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                    n_jobs=1):

train_sizes = [10, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000]

plt.figure()
plt.title(title)
print(ylim)
if ylim is not None:
    plt.ylim(*ylim)
plt.xlabel("Training examples")
plt.ylabel("Score")
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
    estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
plt.grid()


print(train_sizes)
plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                 train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                 color="r")
plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                 test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
         label="Training score")
plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
         label="Cross-validation score")

plt.legend(loc="best")
return plt
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60nZe.png)

Can u see how it still shows 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000

Comment: `train_sizes` are not the axis label parameters, but actual data to be plotted. You should note the red and green circles in your posted image. They correspond to what you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `xticks` argument

```
plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
         label="Cross-validation score", xticks = train_sizes)
```